# Apriori Alg in learning data mining with Python ch4

Tags: python, data-mining, apriori

This is a part of *Apriori* algorithm. We want to get two-item frequent itemsets from one-item frequent itemsets. The code in the book is shown below:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def find_frequent_itemsets(favorable_reviews_by_users, k_1_itemsets, min_support):
    counts = defaultdict(int)
    for user, reviews in favorable_reviews_by_users.items():
        for itemset in k_1_itemsets:
            if itemset.issubset(reviews):
                for other_reviewed_movie in reviews - itemset:
                    current_superset = itemset | frozenset((other_reviewed_movie,))
                    counts[current_superset] += 1
    return dict([(itemset, frequency) for itemset, frequency in counts.items() if frequency >= min_support])
```

I'm confused with this: there is a repeated count. e.g., for one certain user, the sets **{A,B}** and **{B,A}** are the identical. But according to the code below:

```
 for itemset in k_1_itemsets:
     if itemset.issubset(reviews):
         for other_reviewed_movie in reviews - itemset:
         current_superset = itemset | frozenset((other_reviewed_movie,))
             counts[current_superset] += 1
```

when

> itemset==A

it counts **{A,B}**.

when

> itemsets==B

it counts **{B,A}**.

So is the code wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`frozenset`, as well as any `set` is unordered and hashed, including when used as key in a dictionary or generally for comparisons. Printing it can be misleading because the order is somewhat random and can randomly be printed out differently.

```
AB = frozenset(["xyz"]) | frozenset(["abc"])
BA = frozenset(["abc"]) | frozenset(["xyz"])

print(AB == BA)
> True

dct = {}
dct[AB] = "AB"
dct[BA] = "BA"

print(dct)
> {frozenset({'xyz', 'abc'}): 'BA'}
```

In the original algorithm all sets are expected to be ordered, meaning the list of transactions (in this case `reviews`) as well as all keys in `counts` are expected to be ordered.

Comment: ''In the original algorithm all sets are expected to be ordered'', can you explain this?

Comment: The Apriori algorithm uses Itemsets, these per definition are lexicographically sorted. Meaning if you have Itemset {A} and add item B, you get {A,B}, if you have {B} and add A, you get {A,B} as well. You can pick any fixed order but it can't vary during the algorithm. Usually code implementing Itemsets will either use lexicographical order (alphabetic string ordering) all the time or if a structure is used that is not able to save an order (e.g. if in python a `set()`), it is ordered before the operations for Apriori that require the order to be correct.

Comment: Check the original paper on page 4, on the right side: https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/170036.170072. "In order not to replicate different ways of constructing the same itemset, items are ordered and ..." and "For example, let Z = {A, B, C, D, E, F} and assume that the items are ordered in alphabetic order."

Comment: This is because in the algorithm when joining the itemsets from the k-1-sized frequent itemsets, additionally (actually, before) the check that checks if all k-1 are frequent itemsets the joined itemsets are only created if they are the same in the first k-1 items. It is a bit confusingly written in the original paper but check out wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm#Overview --> "for all p ∈ L, q ∈ L where p1 = q1, p2 = q2, ..., pk-2 = qk-2".

Comment: So the k-1-frequent-itemsets p and q are joined to create a bigger k-itemset if: 1) their first k-2 elements are the same (thats why order is necessary) and 2) all the k-1-subsets of the now joined k-itemset are frequent itemsets. Only the k-itemsets that remain after these two checks are then actually counted and checked for minSup in the transactions. In your code that first check seems to be missing. So I would assume your code to be quite a bit slower than a full implementation of Apriori because there can still be many unnecessary counts in a potentially giant transaction database.